# Correlation of Sums of Time Series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

If $x_{t+1} =a x_t + \epsilon$, then what is $\text{cor}(x_t+x_{t+1},x_{t+2}+x_{t+3})$? I am getting, computationally, that it is equal to $\frac{a+a^2}{2}$.

The actual problem I'm working on is converting the autocorrelation of a quarterly variable into an annual one. My boss said that he had worked it out to be just the quarterly autocorrelation to the fourth power, but I did some simulations and discovered that wasn't right. I can figure out the correct value for the annual correlation, but I would appreciate some help figuring out what's going on mathematically.

I tried this for the two period case: $E[(x_{t}+x_{t+1}) (x_{t+2}+x_{t+3})] = E[x_t x_{t+2}]+E[x_t x_{t+3}]+E[x_{t+1} x_{t+2}]+E[x_{t+1} x_{t+3}] = (a + 2a^2 +a^3)E[x]^2$.

I've obviously gone off the rails somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is particularly wrong except for the distinction between covariance and correlation

Presumably $|a| <1$ and $\mathbb E[x_t]=0$ and $\mathbb E[\epsilon_t]=0$ with the $\epsilon_t$s independent.  Let's suppose $\mathrm{Var}(\epsilon_t)=\sigma^2$.  Then

- $\mathrm{Var}(x_t) = \frac{\sigma^2}{1-a^2}$
- $\mathrm{Var}(x_t+x_{t+1}) = \frac{2\sigma^2}{1-a}$
- $\mathrm{Cov}(x_t+x_{t+1}, x_{t+2}+x_{t+3})  = \frac{\sigma^2 a(1+a)}{1-a}= (a+2a^2+a^3)\mathrm{Var}(x_t) = \frac{a+a^2}2 \mathrm{Var}(x_t+x_{t+1})$
- $\mathrm{cor}(x_t+x_{t+1}, x_{t+2}+x_{t+3}) =\frac{\mathrm{Cov}(x_t+x_{t+1}, x_{t+2}+x_{t+3})}{\mathrm{Var}(x_t+x_{t+1})}= \frac{a+a^2}2$

As for your original debate with your boss, there is a distinction between $cor(x_t, x_{t+4})$ and $cor(x_t+x_{t+1}+x_{t+2}+x_{t+3}, x_{t+4}+x_{t+5}+x_{t+6}+x_{t+7})$

Answer (score 0):

You calculated the covariance correctly, you just forgot to divide by the standard deviations to convert it to correlation.